# Can not Update Oracle Database with error code ORA-00933: SQL command not properly ended

Tags: c#, oracle

I am trying to update a record in oracle SQL but can not UPDATE and have error SQL Error: ORA-00933: SQL command not properly ended

```
            using (OracleConnection oc = new OracleConnection())
            {
               string sql = string.Format("UPDATE TABLE01 SET STATUS = '0'  WHERE ID = {0}", dataRequest.ID);

                oc.ConnectionString = CONNECTION_STRING;
                oc.Open();
                using (OracleCommand cmd = new OracleCommand(sql, oc))
                {
                    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                    Console.WriteLine("DONE____________");
                }
            }
```

Comment: What is the **exact** value of `sql`?

Comment: Is `STATUS` field of type `CHAR` or `VARCHAR2`? If **not**, drop `'`: `UPDATE TABLE01 SET STATUS = 0  WHERE ID = {0}`

Comment: STATUS field of type CHAR